# Can you explain the updateForm() function from MongoDB official MERN stack tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am following the [MERN stack tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial) from the MongoDB official website.

In the create.js file we create the `Create` component. Follows the code sample:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

export default function Create() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    position: '',
    level: '',
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // These methods will update the state properties.
  function updateForm(value) {
    return setForm((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, ...value };
    });
  }

  // This function will handle the submission.
  async function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // When a post request is sent to the create url, we'll add a new record to the database.
    const newPerson = { ...form };

    await fetch('http://localhost:5005/record/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(form),
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error);
      return;
    });

    setForm({ name: '', position: '', level: '' });
    navigate('/');
  }

  // This following section will display the form that takes the input from the user.
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Create New Record</h3>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="name"
            value={form.name}
            onChange={(e) => updateForm({ name: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="position">Position</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="position"
            value={form.position}
            onChange={(e) => updateForm({ position: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input
              className="form-check-input"
              type="radio"
              name="positionOptions"
              id="positionIntern"
              value="Intern"
              checked={form.level === 'Intern'}
              onChange={(e) => updateForm({ level: e.target.value })}
            />
            <label htmlFor="positionIntern" className="form-check-label">
              Intern
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input
              className="form-check-input"
              type="radio"
              name="positionOptions"
              id="positionJunior"
              value="Junior"
              checked={form.level === 'Junior'}
              onChange={(e) => updateForm({ level: e.target.value })}
            />
            <label htmlFor="positionJunior" className="form-check-label">
              Junior
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input
              className="form-check-input"
              type="radio"
              name="positionOptions"
              id="positionSenior"
              value="Senior"
              checked={form.level === 'Senior'}
              onChange={(e) => updateForm({ level: e.target.value })}
            />
            <label htmlFor="positionSenior" className="form-check-label">
              Senior
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Create person"
            className="btn btn-primary"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have difficulty to decode what updateForm() does exactly

```
function updateForm(value) {
    return setForm((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, ...value };
    });
  }
```

My questions are:

1. What is the value of `prev` parameter? I don't understand how this works as we don't place any value in this parameter.
2. How `setForm()` manipulates `{ ...prev, ...value }`. Why couldn't we use `setForm({ value })` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question - you can use `setState` in 2 ways:

1. pass value of the new state.
2. pass a callback with argument of the current state, that returns the new state value.

Your second question has nothing to do with react but with *JavaScript*.
it's just a way to merge 2 object, but the duplicate keys will be overridden by the latest value.

The `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) .

```js
let obj1 = {
  a: 2,
  b: 4,
  c: 6
};
let obj2 = {
  c: 8,
  d: 0
};

console.log({ ...obj1,
  ...obj2
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was great! Now about "but the duplicate keys will be overridden by the latest value" i suppose is something setState function is responsible for.